# KnockoutJS - UI not firing onchange event after nested observableArray UI is rendered

Tags: knockout.js

I currently have this running correctly where a dropdownlist selection change will display some text while hiding another piece of text.

**javascript that is fired when a dropdown's value is changed:**

```
window.DropdownValueChange = function(event) {
var jqueryValue = $(event);
jqueryValue.closest('td').find('p').hide();

var className = '.' + event.options[event.selectedIndex].value + '-class';
jqueryValue.closest('td').find(className).show();
}
```

**HTML objects changed:**

```
<p class="male-class">I am a male</p>
<p class="female-class">I am a female</p>
```

However, this is not the case when the HTML is initially rendered. Why is the onchange function not being fired correctly on the load of the UI?

http://jsfiddle.net/djcanseco/duL72/49/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `onchange` isn't firing on page load. This can be resolved by adding a visual data-bind to the `<p>` tags:

```
 <p class="male-class" data-bind="visible: gender == 'male'">
    I am a male
 </p>
 <p class="female-class" data-bind="visible: gender == 'female'">
    I am a female
 </p>
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duL72/51/)

Comment: I attempted to remove the onchange event handler on the dropdownlist thinking the visible section would handle the UI change but it's not working. I don't think the value is being changed in the view model, am I thinking the control is working a different way than it should.

Comment: Figured it out, looks like the fact that I loaded the observableArray with JS objects that they did not mesh correctly since the gender value could not be pulled correctly out of the view model after the initial load. I changed the databind to be `"visible: gender() == 'male'"` instead. Thanks @Jesse for pointing me in the right direction!